# Use RESTful URLs in a non-MVC site

Tags: rest, razor

I started the site using AST.NET Razor template, not ASP.NET MVC template.

I recall seeing somewhere on the Internet that even without MVC, it's possible to use RESTFul URLs in the razor-based ASP.NET site. It appears to work without the CHTML extension names right out of the box -- www.test.com/car automatically redirects to www.test.com/car.cshtml.

But, what if I used www.test.com/car/2, how would I get to the "2" inside the View without using MVC? I really hope that's something already baked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it -- it's in UrlData

http://beta.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/aspnet-razor-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

section "How Routing Works"

Comment: As soon as you are able to, be sure and mark this answer as accepted so others will know there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the WebGet Attribute. It has a UriTemplate.

Example:

```
WebGet(UriTempate="{Id}")<br>
public JsonResult Get(int Id)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not talking about services. The question is whether CSHTML pages receive the parts of a RESTFul URL via some kind of an object model.